# Isolate modus IC

Tags: isolation, rs485

I want to isolate the RO, DI, and RE/DE pins going to the microcontroller. Can someone suggest what sort of IC would be appropriate for this application?

I wanted to use the FOD8012AR2, however, I see it only has 2 channels.

[image]

Update 1:

[image]

Comment: "Isolate" or "buffer"? The MAX485E symbol does not suggest any level of isolation.

Comment: @Transistor Trying to figure out how to explain this. Where I have the ISOLATED word, I want to put another IC that will isolate the RO, DI, DE/RE pins from the max485 to the micro-controller.

Comment: @Transistor please see Update 1 image

Comment: OK. You might want to use the term "opto-isolate". I don't think any other kind of isolation will be suitable.

Comment: @Transistor There are many kinds of isolators, other than optoisolator.

Comment: @JoeyB So if you want isolation, don't you also need to isolate MCU ground and supply from RS-485 transceiver? Why don't you use two of the FOD8012 then? Also, MAX485E is not rated to work at 3.3V so you need to anyway redesign the circuit. And, RS-485 is a three wire interface, two for data and one for ground reference. It is also not a good idea to put the termination resistor onboard unless this is a bus master and it will only be at start of bus. But for ModBus, don't you need failsafe bias resistors, unless this is a sensor.

Comment: You're looking for *digital isolators*, and optos of several types could be used as well. You also need a DC-DC supply.

Comment: @Justme "But for ModBus, don't you need failsafe bias resistors, unless this is a sensor." What are failsafe bias resistors and how do I connect them?

Answer (score 1):

Digi-Key has [41 choices](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/digital-isolators/901?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0R4BOKgBgBYB2EAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfImCqwqSEKkiZchEuRC1W0kACZaVRNCXps%2BIqUgVEReqw7dIIAJIjOeMXgFSiAWj1FZUEAV3UrCgBWECIFFkldADZFIQATHj8wWghHHhiQTgBPdjweDBxUBKA) for you to choose from. You should be able to find one that suits your application.

Perhaps this one from NVE?

(Not promoting Digi-Key, a similar search on Mouser or other venders should yield similar results)

[image]

Comment: I thought suggesting what to buy and from where were not on-topic.

Comment: The OP did not ask where to buy, but did want to know what sort of device. It is ok to suggest in an answer.